# How to go back one page and check which is the page that called that action

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need a back button that gets me back one page, and I need that page cached, so I use:

```
<a id="go-back" href="javascript:history.go(-1)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Back</a>
```

Now, if I go back like that, I want the previous page to be rendered differently. How can I tell which page I came back from?

Comment: Did you consider using the HTTP referer?

Comment: my best guess will be to suggest using the `history.pushState` and the `popstate` event

Comment: @rambii, both document.referrer and $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] are in this scenario empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] should do what you're asking so if you want it to appear differently just

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "webpage.php"){
//Do something different
}
```

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is empty when you go back in history.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this if it is still in the same browser page is to use document.referrer property of the DOM. Then a logical comparison can be made.

```
<script>

if (document.referrer == your_website_url) {
    ...
}

</script>
```

Should that fail to meet your requirements because of iframes or issues, cookies are also a reliable way to do this, as in this example:

```
   $.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"});
```

I'm linking the documentation for this property in case you have issues, below.

[DOM definition for HTTP.referrer](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95229140)